# How to store VBA file stream output also into a variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA function that reads a sheet and writes all founded data to a file.
Now i am trying to re-use this data that is written to the file and store it in a variable for further use.

See my VBA code (simplified):

```
Sub test()
    savename = "exported.json"
    myFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & savename
    Open myFile For Output As #1
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Dim wks As Worksheet
    Set wkb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wks = wkb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    lcolumn = wks.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    lrow = wks.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Dim titles() As String
    ReDim titles(lcolumn)
    For i = 1 To lcolumn
        titles(i) = wks.Cells(1, i)
    Next i
    Print #1, "{"
    For j = 2 To lrow
        For i = 1 To lcolumn
            cellvalue = wks.Cells(j, i)
            Print #1, dq & titles(i) & dq & ":" & dq & cellvalue & dq
        Next i
    Next j
    Print #1, "}"
    Close #1
    a = MsgBox("Saved as " & savename, vbOKOnly)
End Sub
```

I agree that I could do the same steps by contaminate to a string variable, but just curious is it possible to store #1 to a variable?

Comment: Try creating a `String` variable as in `Dim json As String`. Then inside your loop just use `json = json & dq & titles(i) & dq & ":" & dq & cellvalue & dq`.

Comment: Yes, as i said that is the usual way. I was just curious to see if we can store #1 at the end of all this to a variable.

Comment: You could always open it for input once it has been closed, and then read the whole file into a variable using `strInput = Input(LOF(intFile), intFile)`.

Comment: Yes, that is another way, but i don't want to open it again.